# Is there a Mandarin equivalent of the Cantonese term "手尾"?

Tags: translation, mandarin, cantonese

手尾 is a very common Cantonese term, I would like to know what Mandarin term can be the equivalent of it.

The following are from CantoDict dictionary:

> [手尾](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/46732/): (to tie up) loose ends
>
> [冇手尾](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/46574/): fail to finish what one has started; not cleaning up after oneself
>
> [跟手尾](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/40266/): to fix sb else's screwed-up work; to pick up someone's unfinished job
>
> [執手尾](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/48034/): to put things in order; to clean up [華]: 收拾
>
> [手尾長](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/49371/): a problem likely to drag on

Example sentences:

唔好咁**冇手尾**: Don't **leave behind loose ends/ unfinished job** like this

唔好要人**跟(你)手尾**: Don't make people **fix (your) screwed-up work**

你走先啦，我**執埋手尾**就會走㗎啦 : You can leave now, I'll leave after I've **put every things in order**

整傷脊椎骨就**手尾長**啦: The problem would **likely to drag on** if you injury your spine

I have no problem translating the examples above to Mandarin (first to English, then to Mandarin), But I have problem pinpointing a single equivalent term in Mandarin. Is there one?

Or maybe 手尾 is so uniquely Cantonese, it cannot be translated to Mandarin as a single term, and have to be translated differently depend on the context?

Edit:

> 手= hand ; 尾 = the last of
>
> "**手尾**" literally means "**remaining work on hand**"

- 唔好咁**冇手尾**: Don't be so **disregarding to the remaining work on hand**
- 你走先啦，我**執埋手尾**就會走㗎啦: You can leave now, I'll leave after I've **finished the remaining work on hand**
- 唔好要人**跟(你)手尾**: Don't make people **follow up on (your) remaining work on hand**
- 整傷脊椎骨就**手尾長**啦: if you injury your spine, **your remaining work on hand will last a long time**

Answer (score 1):

To express “finish remaining work on hand” can use 收尾 in mandarin. And I think this is the word sounds closest to 手尾。So for 我執埋手尾就會走㗎啦, you can say 我做完收尾工作就走啦

唔好咁冇手尾 can be expressed as （做事）不要有头无尾

唔好要人跟(你)手尾 can be expressed as （做事）不要让别人帮你善后（or “擦屁股” ）

整傷脊椎骨就手尾長啦 probably has no similar expression.

Comment: 整傷脊椎骨就手尾長啦 in Mandarin could be 弄傷脊椎骨就後患無窮了

Comment: more colloquial phrase would be 弄傷脊椎骨的話後患可不少啊

Comment: @Tang Ho right, it's just that normally we don't say that...